# "You have not added any aggregations"

Tags: facebook, aggregation, facebook-opengraph

I'm currently testing the new OpenGrah and I have some troubles.
I created my objects, my actions and my aggregations, but when i want configure my Auth Dialog, I've got the message :
*"You have not added any aggregations. Create aggregation."* in Aggregation Previews menu.
However my aggregation is correctly configure in my open graph dashboard ...

Someone know how to solve that ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some sample data to your aggregations.

Comment: So I added sample data to my aggregation and now I can add my app to my timeline.  But I still can't configure my Auth Dialog and i have the same message :/.